# sed - substitute between pattern on different lines

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a csv file exported from spreadsheet which has, in the last column, sometimes a list of names. The file comes out like this:

```
ag,bd,cj,dy,"ss"
aa,bs,cs,fg,"name1
name2
name3
"
ff,ce,sd,de,
ag,bd,jj,ds,"ds"
fs,ee,sd,ee,"name4
name5
"
```

and so on.

I would like to remove the line feed in the last column between quotes so that the output is:

```
ag,bd,cj,dy,ss
aa,bs,cs,fg,"name1 name2 name3"
ff,ce,sd,de,
ag,bd,jj,ds,"ds"
fs,ee,sd,ee,"name4 name5"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` may be one solution for you:

```
awk '/\"/ {s=!s} {printf "%s"(s?FS:RS),$0}'
ag,bd,cj,dy,ss
aa,bs,cs,fg,"name1 name2 name3 "
ff,ce,sd,de,df
```

---

New solution

```
awk -F\" 'NF==3; NF==2 {s++} s==1 {printf "%s ",$0} s==2 {print;s=0}' | awk '{sub(/ "/,"\"")}1' file
ag,bd,cj,dy,"ss"
aa,bs,cs,fg,"name1 name2 name3"
ag,bd,jj,ds,"ds"
fs,ee,sd,ee,"name4 name5"
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne, that indeed works however I haven't typed my example correctly. The issue is that the last column, if has data, then it's in quotes, and if there is no data is empty. Then the example should be like the one in the edited question above (added quotes and few lines)

Comment: Added a new solution that should work.  Not the best.. (does not like the two `awk` should be one)